# How to echo lines horizontally

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm making a menu with various selection for the user to select, but as soon the row hits 10 the pattern changes. Since the number 10 has two digits of course is going to change patterns. I want to be able to start a new row as soon as each row hits 9 lines to keep the pattern of one digit per row.
Example 1 is what my output currently looks like. How can we approach this solution?

```
Example 1                                    Desired output

1)                                         1)              1)
2)                                         2)              2)
.)                                         .)              .
.)                                         .)              .
9)                                         9)              9)
10)
```

*Sample of my code*

```
echo -e "${MENU}*********************************************${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 1)${MENU} Option 1) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 2)${MENU} Option 2) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 3)${MENU} Option 3) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 4)${MENU} Option 4) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 5)${MENU} Option 5) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 6)${MENU} Option 6) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 7)${MENU} Option 7) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 8)${MENU} Option 8)${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 9)${MENU} Option 9) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 10)${MENU} Option10)  ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 11)${MENU} Option11) ${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${MENU}*********************************************${NORMAL}"
echo -e "${ENTER_LINE}Please enter a menu option and enter or            ${RED_TEXT}enter to exit. ${NORMAL}"
read sub3
while [ sub3 != '' ]
do
if [[ $sub3 = "" ]]; then
  exit;
else
  case $sub3 in
  1) sub_menu4;

  #othersub;
  ;;

  2) clear;
    sub_menu4;

  #othersub;
  ;;

3) clear; 
 sub_menu4;;

4) clear; 
 sub_menu4;;

x)exit;
  ;;

  \n)exit;
  ;;

  *)clear;
  option_picked "Pick an option from the menu";
  sub_menu4;
  ;;
  esac
fi
done
}
```

Comment: use `dialog` command.

Comment: I can't find the man page for `dialog` @PersianGulf

Comment: Can you use something as simple as printf %02d $NUMBER. ? (Or % 2d)

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dialog

Comment: @JeffSchaller when I use `printf "%*s\n" 50 "${MENU}**${NUMBER} 10)${MENU} Option10)  ${NORMAL}"` the only thing that prints is `"${MENU}**${NUMBER} 10)${MENU} Option10)  ${NORMAL}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run this command as an example:

```
clear; tput cup 4 10; printf "Menu Item 1"; tput cup 7 30;  printf "Menu Item 29";tput cup 23 0; printf "Make your selection"
```

Then look at the `man` page of `tput` command to understand how it functions. After that it is simple comparison and screen coordinate arithmetic logic. Looks like you have the grasp of shell scripting. So it should not be too hard to write it